# Do formatting helper methods belong in the model, the view model, or a separate class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model that stores company information, including tax IDs. In the US, these are 9 digit numbers and are typically displayed as ##-#######. However, in my system, I am storing these as strings with no hyphen - since other countries can have identification numbers that differ in length and format, I don't want be limited to a US standard.

Now I want to program my views to display US tax IDs in their "friendly" format. I have this working right now with a helper method I put in the Company model class:

```
public string FormatTaxID(string TaxID)
{
    if (Address.Country == "United States")
        return Regex.Replace(TaxID, @"(\d{2})(\d{7})", "$1-$2");
    else
        return TaxID;
}
```

Then in my view, I'm using:

```
@item.FormatTaxID(item.TaxID)
```

This all works fine, but it doesn't feel right to store a method like this in the model - it feels like this is more of a view/view model responsibility than a model responsibility, as it is solely for presentation.

I am using view models and thought of putting it there, but I I have multiple view models for the underlying model and don't want to repeat code if I don't have to. Also, my view model for the index uses collections and I'm not sure how I would work the method into it:

```
public class CompanyIndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

How would I apply this method to a collection like that?

Another option is creating a new helper/utility class and sticking it in there. What would MVC convention dictate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one-offs, I'd say use the view model. If it's something that you will reuse over and over, move it into a utility class that your views/view models/etc. can reference.

And, there's technically nothing wrong sort of doing it both ways. Put the method in a utility class and then add a property to your view model that returns this, e.g.:

```
public class CompanyIndexViewModel
{
    ...
    public string TaxID { get; set; }

    public string USFormattedTaxID
    {
        get { return Utilities.FormatTaxID(TaxID); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense...what would you do in my case above, where my index view model's property is actually a collection? Is there any way to easily apply this method to the IEnumerable<Company>, or does that force me to take the method call into the view where I am iterating over each company in the collection?

Comment: I just grabbed the view model you posted and added the property there, if `Company` is where the `TaxID` lives then, yes, you would want to put the property that returns the formatted tax id there. If you don't want to put this on your entity, you can always create a `CompanyViewModel` and map your list of `Company` instances into a list of `CompanyViewModel`s. It's largely up to you which is best.

Comment: How about for things like currency formatting? Do you handle the formatting in your view model with a currencyValue.ToString("c"), in which case nearly every property on your view model ends up as a string, or maybe have a strongly-typed Currency datatype and use a DisplayTemplate? Or a UIHint if you don't want to just use a decimal? I have apps where we may do this hundreds of times, and the obvious repetition irks me enormously.

Answer (score 1):

The localized-to-the-Company-context TaxID of the company is properly a property of the Company, and is not a presentation detail.

Comment: I disagree. Localization is firmly in the territory of presentation, not persistence. While perhaps highly unlikely, the formatting of Tax IDs in the U.S. *could* potentially change, in which case you want to be able to change the presentation of the ID rather than each persisted ID in your database.

Comment: There are two formattings of TaxIDs in the US already in common use. Formatting it into the proper form in a read only getter as you've done is a model task. Model and DB representation aren't the same thing, despite the Entity Framework easy view of the universe. I think we're actually in violent agreement based on your answer.

Comment: Further, validating that the taxID is even vaguely valid is business logic, not presentation logic, and would belong in domain model classes, not the view model (and if it needs sufficient validation may even involve workflows with human interactions..., so definitely not a presentation detail...)